# Using a file to create a list but the file has variables in it. How do I make the list contain the variable's value?

Tags: python

I'm writing a script that contains a large list. I'm trying to modify my script so that instead of needing to edit the script directly to add/remove items to this list, it reads lines from a text file. Is it possible to use variables inside of this data file?

For example,
If my text file contains this:

```
thing
number+str(variable)
```

And my script looks like this:

```
import os

variable = '123456'
file = 'C:\whatever.txt'

#make the list 'commands'
with open(file) as f:
        commands = []
        for line in f:
                line = line.replace('\n','')
                commands.append(line)

#make the list 'oldcommands'
oldcommands = ['thing','number'+str(variable)]

print(commands)
print(oldcommands)
```

How do I get both of these outputs to be the same?

This is the result of running the script above:

```
['thing', 'number+str(variable)']
['thing', 'number123456']
```

Formatting the file in a particular way is not a problem, I'm just trying to make my script more modular/portable

Comment: Will your variables always be inside of a `str()`?

Comment: They can be, yes

Comment: use can use `eval` on the strings

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Try to go one step back and explain your goal here. It sounds like there could be a better way of doing this

Comment: You may be right, that I'm asking too specific of a question. What I'm doing is piping these commands to putty using pywinauto and this snip of code
 ````for cmd in commands:
 putty.type_keys(cmd)
 putty.type_keys('{ENTER}')
 time.sleep(.3)````
The point is to try to prompt for variables ahead of time that will be used along the way

Comment: It sounds like you could use the `format`.  As long as you know in advance what variables appear in your text file.  `"variables = {"variable_1": value_1, "variable_2": value_2, ...}`.  Then `for line in f: line.format(**variables)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **(This should work for your case)**

```
import os

variable = '123456'
file = 'C:\whatever.txt'

#make the list 'commands'
with open(file) as f:
        commands = []
        for line in f:
                line = line.replace('\n','')
                if '+' in line:
                   line = line.split('+')
                   line = line[0] + eval(line[1])
                commands.append(line)

#make the list 'oldcommands'
oldcommands = ['thing','number'+str(variable)]

print(commands)
print(oldcommands)
```

Comment: [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)